# Possible timezone parsing error in outlook

Tags: outlook, calendar, icalendar, timezone-offset

I'm trying to make sure this is a problem with outlook.

I am generating an ics file that specifies the timezone of the event:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:www.example.com
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Chicago
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:P1W
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:56bba0729f450
DTSTART;TZID=America/Chicago:20160212T170000
SEQUENCE:0
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTEND;TZID=America/Chicago:20160212T183000
SUMMARY:Beer-o-clock
CLASS:PUBLIC
DTSTAMP:20160210T144122Z
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Chicago
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/Chicago
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZNAME:CDT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0600
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:CST
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0600
DTSTART:19701101T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
END:VCALENDAR
```

This invite works, but if you open it in a different timezone (e.g. I'm seeing this when I open it from the Pacific timezone) in outlook it doesn't recognize the timezone change. The timezone change **is** recognized by other apps like mac os Calendar or Google calendar.

When I rearrange the calendar file so that the `VEVENT` definition is after the `VTIMEZONE` definition it does work in outlook:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:www.example.com
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Chicago
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:P1W
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Chicago
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/Chicago
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZNAME:CDT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0600
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:CST
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0600
DTSTART:19701101T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:56bba0729f450
DTSTART;TZID=America/Chicago:20160212T170000
SEQUENCE:0
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTEND;TZID=America/Chicago:20160212T183000
SUMMARY:Beer-o-clock
CLASS:PUBLIC
DTSTAMP:20160210T144122Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

It seems like this is a parsing error in outlook but I'm not totally sure. I don't know how much control I have over the order in which the ics file is generated without hacking at the vendor code (which I'm hoping not to do).

Is this an outlook specific thing or is there something else wrong with the invite definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iCalendar specifications do not require you to put the `VTIMEZONE` component at the top.  But, of course, people are free to implement the spec however they choose.

Answer (score 0):

While you may not find anything in RFC5545/RFC5546 that would state that VTIMEZONE components have to come before VEVENT, all the examples given in those specifications do put it in that order and the practice is clearly to have VTIMEZONE before VEVENT.
It also simply makes sense from the iCalendar consumer side of things, as the VTIMEZONE TZID is referenced in the VEVENT.

By not following the common practice, you are really asking for trouble. Assuming that you solve your Outlook problem in some other way, you are quite likely to face an interop issue with another client tomorrow. So you are better off fixing your iCalendar stream.